# MySQL searching for data using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this code for searching in the MySQL data table by id, but when I run the program it is giving me this error (Output : "Column 'Mart' Not Found"). I'm using JTextFiled to ask the user to enter the id that want to search for.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource()== btn) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("Select ID,user_name_1,password FROM Admin Where ID = ?");
            int id  = Integer.parseInt(text.getText());
            st.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()==false) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The ID Not Found!!");
            }
            else {
                String user = rs.getString("user_name_1");
                text2.setText(rs.getString(user));
                String pass = rs.getString("password");
                text3.setText(rs.getString(pass));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What in the world is `"Coulmen 'Mart'`? Where could that have possibly come from? Instead of just an exception message, get the entire stacktrace: use `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: (Mart) The user name in MySQL Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if your column names are the same as the ones in the Database
2. Check if your connection string is connecting to the correct database
3. Ensure Database Driver is added

Try this:

```
public class DatabaseClass {

    private String url = "YOUR URL";
    private String username = "YOUR USERNAME";
    private String password = "YOUR PASSWORD";

    private static DatabaseClass theDB = new DatabaseClass();

    private Connection c;

    private DatabaseClass() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Connection: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public Connection getC() {
        return this.c;
    }

    public static DatabaseClass getInstance() {
        return theDB;
    }
}
```

And then, the click event:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            HashMap<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>();

            int id = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
            Connection c = DatabaseClass.getInstance().getC();

            PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement("select * from yourTable where ID = ?");
            s.setInt(1, id);

            ResultSet theResult = s.executeQuery();
            while (theResult.next()) {
                int yourID = theResult.getInt("ID");
                String yourData = theResult.getString("Email_Address");

                data.put(yourID, yourData);
            }

            for (HashMap.Entry theEntry : data.entrySet()) {
                jTextArea1.append(String.valueOf(theEntry.getKey()) + " " + theEntry.getValue() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Ideally this should work, but replace the query with your query and the connection string with yours.

Comment: How can implement your code with Action Listener ?  Because in my code i use Button that user needs to click on it to start searching. For Example: A frame shows up asking the user Entering the ID that want to search for than clicks the button ( Search ). because i m still a beginner i could not implements these thing ( your code and the Action Event for Search Button that i want to do)

Comment: So what you can do is,

1. Attach a click listener to the button
2. Once the button is clicked, retrieve the connection to your database class (ideally via the singleton)
3. Use the connection object to prepare a query and set your params
4. Execute your query

Comment: I will post another answer for this.

Comment: @Maitham refer to the changes i made

Comment: Ensure that the parameters to be retrieved match the column names u have in your database table